# How can i send error text from jersey to js client?

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey

In the server side I return this object `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` to my client.

```
private Response createStatus500(String error) {
    logger.error(error);
    return Response.status(500).type(error).build();
}
```

How can i send some text to the client explaining the error.

because now i cannot get this text in the client side:

```
JSON.stringify(response)
"{"data":"<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"/>\n<title>Error 500 Internal Server Error</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /api/VoicesUploader/uploadFiles. Reason:\n<pre>    Internal Server Error</pre></p><hr><a href=\"http://eclipse.org/jetty\">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.15.v20161220</a><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n","status":500,"config":{"method":"POST","transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"url":"/api/VoicesUploader/uploadFiles","data":{}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing:

return Response.status(500).entity([place a json-string here which contains the error message]).build();